# Easiest PHP Shopping Cart to Skin

Tags: php, shopping-cart, skinning

After frustration with installing custom designed skins for ZenCart, I was wondering which, if any, of the PHP shopping carts out there have a good templating system that makes it easy (or easier) to install custom designs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a project called open cart at http://www.opencart.com/.

It has plugins and a template system so it should be fairly easy skin.

Comment: I have used Opencart and Avactis (see reply below) and by far found Opencart to be much better. It's less bloated and cleaner in code. Avactis seems to be a private project they're charging for and although the latest version has undergone a big revision, it still is slow as mud on some things (in my humble opinion) and has caused database timeouts on shared hosting on a few of the sites we built using it.

Comment: Addendum: Avactis has a lot more features than Opencart and seems a lot more mature in many ways (except as I said above), but Opencart has a community base and extensions being added and incorporated into new releases.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is Avactis shopping cart.

Various dynamic parts of Avactis storefront can be integrated into an existing website through inserting of simple Tags into static pages. All Avactis Tags are described in the Avactis Tag Library

More details:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avactis

Answer (score 0):

Magento is alright to skin, provided you know a bit about Views and also how the layout is controlled.

It's been a while since I used Magento, but from what I can remember is you define a *layout* in an XML file, and then there are many views in a different folder of which you can modify quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is in my opinion Virtuemart 2.

Take a customized template like esport by gavick and you're already on

you can override every page you want, and you take advance of any power of joomla for community extensions